# HP Pavilion DM3 Laptop does not work with ISDN Lines

Tags: windows-7

I have a HP Pavilion DM3 laptop that was purchased in the USA. I need to use it overseas (Greece) where only ISDN internet is available. Windows 7 says that it does not recognize the driver to use it. Is there anyway to get it to support ISDN?

Model: dm3-1039 wm

Comment: do you have an ISDN modem ("terminal adapter")?  i can't imagine your laptop came with one.

Comment: I'm not really sure because it's actually my granpas and the laptop itself is in Greece while I'm in jersey. Let's just assume it doesn't have one. Where can I purchase one of them?